# Stop grep message from posting

Tags: linux, shell, posix

I am working on a script that take 1 string argument and a file. I want it so that if a file is put in that doesn't exist, then it will display the "*filename* cannot be read" message.

That part does work however it also displays a "grep: grep.txt: No such file or directory" message. Is there any way to stop the grep message from posting and ending the script if the first if statement is true?

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ ! -f "$2" ]
then
    echo "$0" cannot be read 1>&2
fi

if [ $# -eq 2 ]
then
    grep "$1" $2
else
    echo there is more or less than 2 arguments 1>&2
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit the script with a non-zero exit code to indicate failure and stop it from continuing on to the `grep`.

```
if [ ! -f "$2" ]
then
    echo "$0" cannot be read 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add /dev/null in grep command it will suppress the error part.

```
grep "$1" $2 2>/dev/null
```

The > operator redirects the output usually to a file but it can be to a device. You can also use >> to append.

`2> file` redirects stderr to file

/dev/null is the null device it takes any input you want and throws it away. It can be used to suppress any output.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect all errors from grep, for example:

`grep "$1" $2 2>/dev/null`

(the `2>` means redirect standard error, as opposed to standard output with `>` or `1>`).

That introduces a race condition, however: if the file disappears while your script as running, it might still exist when you check that it exists, but be gone by the time `grep` runs.

You could handle that by checking the exit status...

```
grep "$1" $2 2>/dev/null
if [[ $? -gt 1 ]]; then
  echo "grep failed unexpectedly" >&2
fi
```

IMHO, in this example it would be better to just let `grep` print the error.